# I would like to know the translation from a small seal script, on an ancient seal, into English

Tags: translation, seal

The seal represents an imperial dragon in red porfido stone. On the lateral of the base, it seems that is written "Year of the dragon, Hu Zhengyan", the 1584-1674, printer, artist and seals carver.

2. On the base of the seal is in the "Small Seal Script", imperial red background. That I do not know how to decipher. It should be the name of the nobleman to whom the seal was carved for signature.

I would like to know what it says.

[image: small script seal writing]

Many thanks in advance
Aurelio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a seal, you have to flip the image to see the correct text

[image]

桐 = 桐樹 (tung tree)

雨 = rain

樓 = building

桐雨樓 /Tóng yǔ lóu/: Mansion Tung and Rain

**Edit:**

I did a search and now I think 桐雨樓 may not be a building but an artist's or an art house's name. It is more likely for a person or organization to have a seal instead of a building having one

From [ArtFox](https://www.artfoxlive.com/product/4912137.html)

> Home > Auction >  香港星辉国际拍卖有限公司艺术品拍卖会 秋季拍卖网拍—中国书画专场网拍  >  金石篆刻—**中国名家印章** >  Lot.138 奚岡刻**桐雨楼**平头章

中国名家印章 = China's famous artist's seal

桐雨樓 should be transliterated as Tong Yu Lou /Tóng yǔ lóu/

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tang. You are right, in seals you have to use the mirror image. Tung is the oil tree. So in theory, it is the seal of a nobiliary family mansion or has another meaning in chinese culture?.

Comment: Dear Tang, Mansion Tung and Rain: it is the seal of a nobiliary family mansion or has another meaning in chinese culture? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Aurelio RZ see my edition

Comment: We have: 庚辰年 胡正言  Geng Chennian Hu Zhengyan: Year of Dragon, Hu Zhengyan. The seal says: 桐雨樓 /Tóng yǔ lóu/: Mansion Tung and Rain.
The famous printer, artist and seal carver Hu Zhengyan made this seal for the “Mansion Tung & Rain” in 1640. He was at the end of the Tang Dynasty and Beginning of Qing.

We found as well the seal at ARTFOX Auction House, with the same “Mansion Tung & Rain” seal, in Shoushan stone (which seems to be the same in ours), by Xi Gang (1746-1803), seals craver, calligraph and painter by the Qing Dynasty.

What is “Mansion Tung & Rain”?